Deduplicate data in ClickHouse when a member of the sort key can change
I'm struggling a bit with deduplication and I was wondering if you had an idea on how we could solve this:

We have a SharedMergeTree table that stores events (1B+ rows). We currently have this PK: (event, flowGroup, flowId, timestamp). It contains other columns, as well as a unique id.
The timestamp column is calculated so when we receive multiple requests for the same event, timestamp can change. It means we can't use the ReplacingMergeTree with this sort key because it would only work if the reinsert comes from a retry, not different requests. The PK needs to be a prefix of the sort key too so we can't have the timestamp only in the PK.
Because materialized views are just insert triggers, we can't use them to deduplicate the data by having an input ReplacingMergeTree table with just the id in the sort key, and a materialized view to output the data to another table with the desired PK.
We tried using a subquery in the INSERT statement to check if the data already exists, but while it works logically, we hit performance issues.

insert into tracks
select
  'xxx' as event,
  'yyy' as flowGroup,
  'zzz' as flowId,
  '2021-01-01 00:00:00.123' as timestamp,
  '2021-01-01 00:00:00.012' as originalTimestamp,
  '1234' as id
where not exists (
  select 1 from tracks
  where
    -- Narrow down by the PK before checking the id
    event = 'xxx'
    and flowGroup = 'yyy'
    and flowId = 'zzz'
    -- Timestamp can change, but will always be equal or greater than originalTimestamp
    and timestamp >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.012'
    and id = '1234'
)

I considered storing just the id in a separate table and do a lookup by ID but my understanding is that the performance of selecting unique IDs from huge tables isn't great either. Maybe a table that has (event, flowGroup, flowId, id) would make the lookup faster? It would still potentially contain a large number of rows for a single combination of event, flowGroup, flowId.
We have a decent amount of duplications ingested (~416k duplicated rows out of ~24.5M ingested events for 1 week) so I'm pretty sure mitigating that would improve performance quite a bit as well as reducing storage. This is not a problem for querying as we just group data so duplicates aren't accounted for.
Thank you!

Just curious: is the performance of FROM tablename FINAL an issue?

@RichRaposa Yes it is, and I don't have problems on the query side. I'm already grouping data with values that are the same on all duplicates so I don't count dupes.
What I want is to mitigate duplicates in the first place for the sake of optimizing storage and performance by decreasing the queryable data if that makes sense.
Thanks!
